# Search MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

Hey, I have put together an iPhone web app and i'm currently reading and displaying data from a MySQL database. I have added a search bar to this page and was wondering what the best way would be to search the content on the page.

[My page](http://m.belfi.co.uk/storelist.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be via AJAX. When you click "Search", make an AJAX call with the supplied search string to a PHP page. The PHP page will then take that string and make a MySQL call that will return the data set. The PHP can then return the dataset back to your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks, have you got any examples or tutorials?

Comment: yep, check it out here:
http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/